# sql trigger not working/updating table

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I had this trigger working fine on another sql server/database.. Now it does nothing, any prerequisites I need to setup or ideas why this isn't working.. SQL Server 2008

```
create trigger Autoupdate6 -- Creating Trigger
On NumericSamples
For Insert
As
Insert Into BM1OILT
Select SampleDateTime, SampleValue From NumericSamples 
Where TagID = 8 and UpdateC = 0
UPDATE NumericSamples set UpdateC = 1 WHERE TagID = 8
go
```

Thanks,

Figured it out, the program that was inserting into the table was doing bulk inserts, there for by passing the triggers.. Went with a job instead of triggers. Thanks again Aaron Bertrand for trying to figure this out with me.

Comment: Are you sure it should be affecting any rows? E.g. maybe no rows are getting inserted with TagID = 8 or UpdateC = 0. Anyway your trigger is looking at the whole table - you should be restricting your queries to rows that are found in the `inserted` pseudo-table.

Comment: There are about a 1000 rows that meet this criteria. This just clicked in my brain, I was doing single row insert test on the other table, now it is trying to do multiple rows.. Could this be the problem, how would I rewrite this..

Comment: Do you have 5 other triggers on this table?

Comment: This is the only one. Does the trigger look like it should work? or do I need to start rewriting it..

Comment: Why is it called `Autoupdate6`?

Comment: I had a written 6 triggers, when nothing worked, I deleted them all, and just started working on one trigger, to try to get at least one to work.. They were all the same except for the tables and criteria.

Comment: Well you know you can `ALTER` a trigger, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will prevent the trigger from attempting to operate on the entire table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Autoupdate6
ON dbo.NumericSamples
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.BM1OILT(...column names here please...)
    SELECT SampleDateTime, SampleValue FROM inserted
    WHERE TagID = 8 AND UpdateC = 0;

  UPDATE n SET UpdateC = 1
    FROM dbo.NumericSamples AS n
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON n.SampleDateTime = i.SampleDateTime
    WHERE n.UpdateC = 0 AND n.TagID = 8;
END
GO
```

You might be able to collapse this to one statement using the `OUTPUT` clause, but there are so many limitations on composable DML, it's usually just wasted effort unless we already know that your environment is not subject to any of the restrictions.

Comment: What would I put as my key_column name? it gets an error there. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @PatPav does your table have a primary key? Try that.

Comment: I added a primary key to the BM1OILT, the NumericSamples already had a primary key. Tried a few different variations, but still no luck. Is there some setting that I am missing sql? I guess I'll try to remote to my other sql server tonight, and see if I can delete recreate the trigger and see if the trigger is still works, maybe I did something before, that I forget to do this time..

Comment: @PatPav *sigh* what is the primary key on NumericSamples?

Comment: SampleDateTime. Sorry if I am being curt : (, I've been sitting here for 6 hours messing with this.. When I had it working on my test machine a few weeks ago.. Just is frustrating.. When I did it before with my original trigger, I'd get like 40 rows updated.. now nothing..

Comment: @PatPav ok, check the update then. If you can't work it out from there, *shrug*

Comment: I am at a loss to, thanks for the help!! It is like the trigger isn't running or something.. Maybe I'll make some new tables and make a super easy trigger and see if it even works..

Comment: Its wierd. I take away the trigger part and the code runs perfect.. its like the trigger isnt executing at all or when new data is added even. Ive added ass many permissions as I can find etc..